# Paramiko and Crypto Import Error: import winrandom (python)

Tags: python, paramiko, pycrypto

Running on a windows machine python 2.7, whenever I try to run my script using the command line I receive the following error.

```
import winrandom
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

But this error does not happen when I run my script through a python IDE

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your PATH correctly includes your python2.7 and python2.7\Scripts directories.

Snippet on settings environment variables (if needed):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx